# User input reading without return in julia

Tags: io, julia

When using `read(STDIN)` or `readlines()` the function only receives the text after pressing return. How can I get the input of only a letter without waiting the return?

Comment: are you trying to read user input from the REPL?

Comment: @FelipeLema no, it’s a program in execution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not about Julia but rather about your environment. The terminal buffers the characters until it sees a `\n` or `EOF` character and then puts the characters in `STDIN`. You can bypass this behavior by going into `raw mode` which directly sends the pressed characters to `STDIN`. In Julia, you can do this by making a system call with `run`. The following works if you are on Linux:

```
run(`stty raw`)
read(STDIN, Char)
```

You can go back to the (probably) default mode with

```
run(`stty cooked`)
```